# "Not Found" exception from AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1 when calling Get-AzTableRow immediately after Get-AzTableTable

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I have a PowerShell script in which I call Get-AzTableTable, Get-AzTableRow, and Add-AzTableRow one after another. Sometimes (but not always), I get the following error from Get-AzTableRow:

```
Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "Not Found"
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzTable\2.0.2\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:239 char:10
+ ...      return ($Table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperat ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException
```

This appears to happen only when the table doesn't already exist. I think what's happening is that Get-AzTableTable is creating it asynchronously (via $Table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()), and I'm calling Get-AzTableRow before the table has been created.

What's the solution to this problem? How can I ensure the table has been created before I check for the existence of a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a loop(like while) to determine if the table exists, after create the table using `$Table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()`.

Sample code like below:

```
#create the table using $Table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()

#here check if the table create or not
# Since I cannot see all your code, note that if $Table does not have a method Exists(), you can try use $Table.CloudTable.Exists()
while(!($Table.Exists()))
{
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2; 
Write-Output "the table does not create, please wait."
}

#if the table exists, you can do other operation.
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try the solution yet, but yes, waiting for the table to be created sounds like it would work. A wait with a sleep seems like a clunky solution though, but it will work in a pinch.